# find url in html code

Tags: php, text, filter, find

I want tu find url in html code with PHP or JS 
e.g i have this text

```
<description>
<![CDATA[<p>
<img" src="http://2010.pcnews.am/images/stories/2011/internet/chinese-computer-user-smoke.jpg" border="0" align="left" "/>
Երեկ Պեկինի ինտերնետ-սրճարաններից մեկում մահացել է 33-ամյա մի չինացի, ով  27 օր շարունակ անցկացրել էր համակարգչի առաջ:  Հաղորդում է չինական «Ցյանլունվան» պարբերականը:</p>
<p>Աշխատանք չունեցող չինացին  մեկ ամիս շարունակ չի լքել ինտերնետ-սրճարանը ՝ այդ ամբողջ ընթացքում սնվելով արագ պատրաստվող մակարոնով:</p>
<p />

Նույնիսկ ամանորյա տոները նա անցկացրել է համակարգչի առաջ. Պեկինի բնակիչները նշում են Նոր տարին Լուսնային օրացույցով՝ փետրվարի 3-8-ը: Մահվան պատճառները չեն հաղորդվում:
]]>
</description>
```

i want take only `"http://2010.pcnews.am/images/stories/2011/internet/chinese-computer-user-smoke.jpg"` , 
Thank in advance

Comment: I dont know if its my browser, but what I see is hibru or something on the screen with no html tags!! can you include them so I can help you out

Comment: you can use regular expressions see http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/

Comment: Read [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) before choosing a solution with regexes!

Comment: See my answer for actual working code that doesn't use regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather complicated task and while regex may seem easier, it is far too problematic. The following code will go through an XML file (called *some.xml*, but you’ll obviously need to change that) and gather the image sources into an array, `$images`.

```
$images = array();

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('some.xml');

$descriptions = $doc->getElementsByTagName("description");
foreach ($descriptions as $description) {
    foreach($description->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeType == XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE) {
            $html = new DOMDocument();
            @$html->loadHTML($child->textContent);
            $imgs = $html->getElementsByTagName('img');
            foreach($imgs as $img) {
                $images[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it against the XML you supplied an got the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://2010.pcnews.am/images/stories/2011/internet/chinese-computer-user-smoke.jpg
)
```

I put it into an array in case there is more than one `description` with images.

Comment: You could probably short-circuit this with an XPath query at the beginning, but props for the code example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript or jQuery to get the image's src attribute.

```
document.getElementsByTag("img")[x].src
```

Comment: jQuery: `$("img").attr("src");`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to find content between `src="` and preceding `"`

Comment: Read this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 0):

In php could be done like this:

```
<?php

$txt = 'text here <img src="http://domain.com/something.png" border="0" align="left" "/> more
test and <em>html</em> around here
<p> thats it </p>';

preg_match('/src="([^"]*)"/', $txt, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks VSS, I never said it was a good idea. I know there's at least one person who'll point out that `using php to parse html is bad practice` with questions like these so I just focus on showing how it can be done. Though I have to admit I don't see a small task like this as parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are brittle for text parsing and do not take advantage of the document's inherent structure. Using RegEx to find stuff in a marked up document is generally a poor practice.

Use PHP's built in [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) and [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) instead.